# Z3 code in python

Tags: python, z3

i have installed both python and Z3 and have set PYTHONPATH with the path of Z3 python directory.

I import Z3 by running this,
from z3 import *

But after this i am getting a persistent long error message of which ends in the following manner:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-4.1\python\z3core.py", line 34, in init
    _lib = ctypes.CDLL(PATH)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Interestingly everything was working till i reinstalled both python and Z3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PATH environment variable should be set to include the bin or the x64 directory in the Z3 installation. If you are using the 64 bit version of Python you should include the x64 directory.

Example:

> hello.py
>     ....
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 365, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>     WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-4.1\bin
>
> hello.py
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     ....
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 365, in **init**
>         self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>     WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-4.1\x64
>
> hello.py
>     hello Z3

Comment: i did try this but didnt work. I have a 32 bit machine, but i cant see this program Files(x86) folder there, i have my installation in Program Files folder.

Comment: On 32-bit Windows there is only one `Program Files` folder. On 64-bit Windows there are two, `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`. So, in your case removing the `(x86)` from Nikolaj's example should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, it turned out to be because I didn't have dlls libz3 was dependent on. 
solved by installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Answer (score 0):

If you use anaconda, using the following command would suffice to install z3.

```
pip install z3-solver
```